# Why was this migrated?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

Why was [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56580/teens-on-an-island-forced-to-kill-each-other-collars-prevents-co-operation) migrated to Sci Fi Stack Exchange?

I get why it is linked to the Sci Fi, as the OP discusses both a book and a movie and it *does* have a science fiction story... But the fact there IS a movie (and a famous movie at that, with a close correlation with The Hunger Games) surely means it could have had a place on this site too.

Is there any reason it *had* to be migrated? Couldn't it have existed on both sites with each site offering different answers (e.g. ours focusing solely on movie aspects)?

Comment: Good question. Maybe a cross-site-question that got merged? Are you sure it was migrated?

Comment: @atticae: I'm assuming so. It still appears as one of the Top Questions on the main site, as this: "Teens on an island, forced to kill eachother, collars prevents co-operation [migrated]"

Comment: It was an intentional cross-post in the first place (as can also be seen in the fact that the migrated question has immediately been closed as a duplicate).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [edit history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/56580/revisions) suggests that it was merged with [this duplicate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56655/teens-on-an-island-forced-to-kill-eachother-collars-prevents-co-operation) on SciFi.

The user posted the same question on two sites in the SE network, [which is a no-go](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). So merging them makes sense. I assume we drew the short straw because we are Beta, so the question went to SciFi.

Considering that it is an ID question, I am not really sorry about it, though. ;)

Comment: The short straw (which I agree is actually the longer one) might also have been because the question was also concerned with the bigger picture of a probable book source and such things. So it might have been deemed more appropriate on [scifi.se].

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: Good point.

Comment: I dislike this. I understand the logic of not posting identical questions on two sites, but I'd rather leave this one open and simply edit it to make it a pure id question - especially since it was answered and a decent question.

Comment: Yeah it is unfortunate when this happens because one of the community loses content. I still think it's important to discourage users from spamming their questions across multiple sites to get maximum coverage.

Comment: @AndrewMartin Well, that is *always* the problem when closing duplicates that already have an answer, even for intra-site duplicates (which I hope you wouldn't propagate), but nevertheless they're duplicates, which ought to be closed. A better way would be the option to merge the answers of the duplicate into its predecessor but that brings other problems, like e.g. in this case the answers were themselves more or less duplicates of answers to the other question (or even duplicates of answers to the same question for that matter ;-().

Comment: I believe this is correct - the question is perfectly on-topic here, but is a cross site duplicate.  It would not have been migrated purely for being SciFi.

Comment: Yeah, that's fair enough. I thought it had been migrated purely as it was felt to be a "better fit" over at the Sci Fi. I get it if it's a cross site dupe.

Comment: I worked with mods over at SciFi to come to a mutual decision.  Cross-site spamming isn't fun [*I lay out the general rules on this here*](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/550/asking-duplicate-questions-from-scifi-to-gain-movie-perspective/551#551)

Comment: I flagged it there and here at the time, and asked the user on the SF site not to crosspost.